# How do I check for specific characters in a string and return the amount of them?

Tags: java

so I'm a completely new programmer in Java and I'm trying to figure out how to return the number of lowercase 'e' and uppercase 'E' given user input using JOptionPane.showInputDialog. Here is my current program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int lowerCaseLetters = 0; // I will use this variable to count 'e'
    int upperCaseLetters = 0; // This variable will be used to count 'E'
    String wordInput; // this is the input for program.
    
    while(true) { // a while loop to continue looping until "STOP" is entered as input
    
    wordInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a sentence: "); // asking user for input
        for (int i = 0; i < wordInput.length(); i++) {
            lowerCaseLetters = wordInput.charAt('e');
            if (lowerCaseLetters == 'e')
                lowerCaseLetters++;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Number of lower case e's: " +lowerCaseLetters);
            
        }
        if (wordInput.equalsIgnoreCase("stop")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ending program. "); 
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

}

For example, I'm trying to write the program so that it returns something like this in the JOptionPane.showMessageDialog box when the program asks for input:

Entering the word "Ethereum" would output:

Number of lowercase e's: 2

Number of uppercase E's: 1

and entering a word or sentence with no E's will prompt for user to try again.

Comment: Copying and pasting code is almost as easy as taking a screenshot and pasting here. So, why not make it easier for the people you are asking help from? Edit your post and copy and paste the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to find out duplicates using HashMap.

```
 public static void printDuplicateCharacters(String word) {
        char[] characters = word.toCharArray(); // build HashMap with character and number of times they appear in
        Map<Character, Integer> charMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        for (Character ch : characters) {
            if (charMap.containsKey(ch)) {
                charMap.put(ch,
                        charMap.get(ch) +
                            1);
            } else {
                charMap.put(ch, 1);
            }
        }
        Set<Map.Entry<Character, Integer>> entrySet = charMap.entrySet();
        System.out.printf("List of duplicate characters in String '%s' %n", word);
        for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : entrySet) {
            if (entry.getValue() > 0) {
                System.out.printf("%s : %d %n", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Define your input, and a `Map` to hold results of analysis. Use a `LinkedHashMap` to keep keys in the order in which they were inserted.

```java
String input = "Ethereum";
Map < Integer, Integer > mapOfCodePointToOccurrences = new LinkedHashMap <>();
```

Avoid using the `char` type. As a 16-bit value, `char` in incapable of representing most characters. The `char` type has been essentially broken since Java 2, and legacy since Java 5+ when code point related methods were added to various classes.

Instead use [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) integer numbers when working with individual characters.

Calling `String#codePoints` generates an `IntStream` of code points, a sequence where each element is the code point number for the nth character. Boxing turns the `int` primitives into `Integer` objects. Collect those into a [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html).

```java
List < Integer > codePoints = input.codePoints().boxed().toList();
```

Determine a distinct list of those code points, eliminating duplicates.

```java
List < Integer > distinctCodePoints = codePoints.stream().distinct().toList();
```

Loop each of those distinct code points. Search the list of all code points to count occurrences. Put the count into the map.

```java
for ( Integer distinctCodePoint : distinctCodePoints )
{
    long count = codePoints.stream().filter( codePoint -> codePoint == distinctCodePoint ).count();
    mapOfCodePointToOccurrences.put( distinctCodePoint , Math.toIntExact( count ) );
}
```

Report the results. For each code point key in our map, make a one-character string by calling [`Character.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#toString(int)).

```java
// Report
for ( Map.Entry < Integer, Integer > integerIntegerEntry : mapOfCodePointToOccurrences.entrySet() )
{
    String message = "Count of « " + Character.toString( integerIntegerEntry.getKey() ) + " » is " + integerIntegerEntry.getValue();
    System.out.println( message );
}
```

When run:

```
Count of « E » is 1
Count of « t » is 1
Count of « h » is 1
Count of « e » is 2
Count of « r » is 1
Count of « u » is 1
Count of « m » is 1
```

Dump other content to console.

```java
System.out.println( "codePoints = " + codePoints );
System.out.println( "distinctCodePoints = " + distinctCodePoints );
System.out.println( "mapOfCodePointToOccurrences = " + mapOfCodePointToOccurrences );
```

When run:

```
codePoints = [69, 116, 104, 101, 114, 101, 117, 109]
distinctCodePoints = [69, 116, 104, 101, 114, 117, 109]
mapOfCodePointToOccurrences = {69=1, 116=1, 104=1, 101=2, 114=1, 117=1, 109=1}
```

As a beginner, you may not yet be comfortable with streams. You can just as well replace the use of streams here with loops. The only exception is the first stream, to get the code points of input. Here is code to transform that first stream into an array of code point integer numbers.

```
int[] codePoints = input.codePoints().toArray() ;
```